# Removing rows of a matrix in a loop based on their index

Tags: r

In a loop, I identify rows based on a test. I iteratively remove those rows from the original matrix (inM) using their index (idx):

```
 inM <- inM[-idx,]
```

Sometimes, idx is empty, i.e. no row satisfies the test, thus idx is of type integer(0).
Removing idx from inM gives then a empty matrix rather than the same matrix. As a result, I got a empty matrix for the following iteration...

Is there a one-liner solution to avoid that?

Comment: Yes, add a condition to check whether idx is empty or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid `if` by using `?setdiff` function:

```
inM <- inM[setdiff(1:nrow(inM), idx), ]
```

Comment: `if (length(idx)) inM <- inM[-idx,]` is more efficient than this, especially if the matrix is large and if `idx` is often empty. It is better to say "do nothing" than to say "assign to `inM` all its elements again" which is what this answer does

Comment: @sieste a solution based on a if it's definitely better efficient than a setdiff even if this one is smart

Answer (score 0):

you can add a condition in your loop for instance:

```
if (length(idx)==0)
  next
```

like this if there is no rows to delete you pass to the next iteration.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to avoid the `if`?